# Compare row entry with one or more previous rows value in apache-spark

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe with the following setup:

| Index | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 4 | b |
| 5 | c |
| 7 | g |
| 8 | g |
| 10 | g |
| 12 | c |
| 13 | g |
| 15 | c |

And I want to only select those events where the value g is directly followed by a g in the next row. I want to do this with the help of the Spark Structured Streaming API for JAVA, but I simply can not figure out a SQL statement or how to do it with the given operations/transformations of the API. The Index is increasing but not in a foreseeable way. I am getting streaming input from Kafka. If possible I would prefer a solution without using windows and an easy way of adjusting how often "g" has to follow each other. I really tried finding something with using for example the LAG SQL statement but I failed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lead()`:

```
select index, value
from (select t.*,
             lead(value) over (order by index) as next_value
      from t
     ) t
where next_value = 'g';
```

Comment: Thanks! This already helped me! Seems like i simply reversed lag and lead... But do you also know how i could adjust this so that i could check for a "g" following "g" 5 or 6 times in a row?

Comment: @Daevaisus . . . That would be a different question.  You should ask as a *new* question, not in a comment or by continually revising an existing question.